# DBT and Liquibase (creates the tables)

Tags: python, sql, analytics, liquibase, dbt

I'm about to start implementing dbt (https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/about/viewpoint) and liquibase, but I find that there will be a functionality overlay between dbt and Liquibase (dbt creates the tables if they don't exist). I would like to know if anyone in the community knows how to solve this. Or what advice could you give me

Thank you

Santiago

Answer (score 2):

At our company, we use Liquibase to create all tables (and other DDL) that contain actual data (that is not coming from another table in the DWH). In DBT they call these data tables sources.

I see the tables you create using DBT as ephemeral. If performance wasn't an issue, I would create all DBT tables as SQL views. Because of 'Big Data' nowadays, performance is an issue and you can't just execute the full SQL query every time you want to display some statistic. That's way you use DBT to create these tables in an incremental way. (next to the templating you can do in DBT)